# How in a bluetooth connection can the Peripheral get the Central device name

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, bleno

Is there any way for a Peripheral to get a Central device's name when establishing a bluetooth connection (BLE)? I'm unsure if Bleno has the tools necessary to get this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read the Device Name in the remote GATT server. The peripheral must support GATT client in order to be able to read the device name.

Comment: I always understood that the GATT client was central, and the peripheral the server, so here are you suggesting my peripheral should/could also be the GATT client?

Comment: Wrong, peripheral/central is a concept in GAP and relates to advertising, scanning and connection establishment. It has nothing to do with GATT. As can be read in Bluetooth Core specification v5.2, Vol 3 Part C (Generic Access Profile), section 15.2: Devices implementing either the LE Peripheral or LE Central role must always implement a GATT Server (mandatory). GATT Client is optional. So yes a peripheral can also be GATT client.

Comment: Ok that really clarifies things. Thanks a bunch!